# Python lambda ReverseMap

Tags: python, recursion, lambda

I can't get my reverseMap program to work. Any tips?

The case of the practise:
*reverseMap takes as input a function (f), and two numbers (current and threshold). It creates a string recursively: at every recursive step it applies the function f to the number "current" and the result is combined (in reverse order) with the result of the recursive call to reverseMap where the value current gets increased (until it reaches threshold, then it stops).


f1 multiplies the input by 5

f2 increases the input by 1

ProgramTest1: uses f1

ProgramTest2: uses f2

ProgramTest3: hidden*

```
def reverseMap(f, current, threshold):
  if___==___:
    return 'Result:'
  else:
  ___________________________
  ___________________________
  ___________________________

f1 = lambda ___  
f2 = lambda ___  
n = 10
res = reverseMap(f1, 1, n)
print()
```

In the exercise I can see that the result will be:
Globals:
f1 = ref_1
f2 = ref_2
n = 10
res = 'Result:␣45␣40␣35␣30␣25␣20␣15␣10␣5'
reverseMap = ref_0

So with this information I can come up with this:

```
def reverseMap(f, current, threshold):
  if current == 0:
    return 'Result:'
  else:
  ___________________________
  ___________________________
  ___________________________

f1 = lambda x: x * 5  
f2 = lambda x: x + 1 
n = 10
res = reverseMap(f1, 1, n)
print()
```

What do I have to fill in the blank spaces?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def reverseMap(f, current, threshold):
    if current == threshold:
        return 'Result:'
    new_result = reverseMap(f, f2(current), threshold)
    result =  new_result + ' ' + str(f(current))
    return result

f1 = lambda x: x*5
f2 = lambda x: x+1

n = 10
res = reverseMap(f1, 1, n)
print(res)
res = reverseMap(f2, 1, 7)
print(res)
```

Comment: Thanks for your code! Problem is.. I can only fill in code were I put the ____.
After that, the code will be tested. That means in Test 1 the lambda f1 is used which has to give the result: 'Result:␣45␣40␣35␣30␣25␣20␣15␣10␣5'
In test 2 the f2 lambda will be used as input so the result has to be: 'Result:␣7␣6␣5␣4␣3␣2'

I have to work with lambdas

Comment: Revised as above.

Comment: Thanks for your help. With this code, the exercise is correct.
What steps did you follow when doing the exercise?
I don't quite understand the step 'new_result = reverseMap (f, f2 (current), threshold)'. Do you have any tips for me if I come across another exercise like this later. Regards

Comment: function defined as reverseMap(f, current, threshold), means to do f(current) until 'current' reach 'threshold', f2(current) means to change the value of 'current', then do reverseMap again.